# why in this code would I be getting "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, option-type, optional-parameters

Here is the code below:

```
private func getReverseGeocodeData(newCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLPlacemark? {
  let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinates.latitude, longitude: newCoordinates.longitude)
  GCAnnotation.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, error in
    if let pms = placemarks {
      let pm : CLPlacemark? = pms.first as CLPlacemark?
      return pm // ==> "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: i.e. I've cast pm as an optional and returning this...so shouldn't this work?

Comment: The closure containing `return pm` doesn't specify a return value, only the outer function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a callback parameter in your function that you can call after the reverseGeocodeLocation is finished and pass the pm as parameter.

```
private func getReverseGeocodeData(callback : (CLPlaceMark?)-> Void, newCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLPlacemark? {
  let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinates.latitude, longitude: newCoordinates.longitude)
  GCAnnotation.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, error in
    if let pms = placemarks {
      let pm : CLPlacemark? = pms.first as CLPlacemark?
       callback(pm)
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GCAnnotation.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) is in it's own closure and function. When you use a callback like that you can't return a value like that. However if you are sure that that function returns a value immediately you could the following:

```
private func getReverseGeocodeData(newCoordinates : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLPlacemark? {
    let pm: CLPlacemark?
    let clLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinates.latitude, longitude: newCoordinates.longitude)
    GCAnnotation.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(clLocation) { placemarks, error in
        if let pms = placemarks {
             pm = pms.first as CLPlacemark?
        }
    }
    return pm
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it will always return before the completion handler is called and return `nil` every time.

Comment: ok - so that kind of implies that if you need to call the reverseGeocodeLocation function in a few places you may as well call it directly in each of these places, as opposed to try to putting it into it's own function like I've done.  As you have to really carry out what you want to do in the call back anyway.  Make sense?

Comment: Yeah pretty much, you can also of course request a callback as a parameter in the function and pass the data back with that.